# Correct REST URI Syntax

Tags: rest

I've seen some people say that this is the only way to do REST:

```
/car
```

Displays all cars

```
/car/123
```

Displays information about the car with ID of 123

I have also seen others that prefer to do this with REST:

```
/car
```

Displays all cars

```
/car?id=123
```

Displays information about the car with ID of 123

Which is correct for REST?

Please note that I am only posting this question to get a real answer, I am not trolling.  If REST is not defined enough for a definitive answer, or it is not clear which option above is "correct" for REST, then that would be a fine answer for me.  I am simply trying to understand REST.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll find this talk interesting: [link](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/slides_for_restful_api_design_second_edition_webinar)

Comment: REST is a distributed application architectural style and as such, it defines a complex set of practices. The best introduction to REST that I've seen so far is the [REST in Practice book.](http://restinpractice.com/book/) REST is much more than designing URIs but unfortunately, REST has become a synonym for HTTP which it is **not**. Both Tom & Justin provide popular but misleading information about REST. Do yourself a favor and take the time to understand what REST actual is.

Answer (score 3):

REST was originally designed based on a purely path-driven architecture, although different implementations of REST APIs in software like Flickr and JIRA have clouded this a bit. In the end what is most important is that the standards used within the entirety of your own API are consistent (i.e. don't use /api/user/21 for getting a user and then /api/group?id=3 for another). Ideally, use paths to locate a resource and then use different HTTP verbs to determine what you're doing with that resource (GETing it, POSTing a new one, PUTting an update, etc).

Wikipedia has a very informative article on it.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer